# How to provide check boxs in VS.net setup dialog?

Tags: c#

I have an exe, I have created setup for that in Vs.net. Now my question is, how do I provide check boxes in setup dialog for asking "Launch the application", "Set in startup" and "Create Shortcut in desktop "?

Can any one help me on this regard ?
Thanks in advance,
Ravi Naik.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're asking, but check out [**Checkboxes User Interface Dialog Box**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b5sy4ht.aspx).

Comment: I have tried as mentioned there, but even if i say no need to create shortcut on desktop it is creating shortcut in desktop :(